# Call the same function in different classes

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I have a function `eventIterable()` in six different classes, each with different names. These classes are being stored in an `Object[]`.

I have a custom `ArrayList` class (I had to create my own - long story, don't bother suggesting I use the standard one), and within it, you can access indexes from the `ArrayList`.

Each of these class objects are stored at an index in the array list. However, since the type of the array is `Object`, I can't call the functions. I can't change from `Object` to a specific class because each of the classes is unique. They all share the `eventIterable()` function, however.

The goal is to be able to iterate through all of the classes in the `ArrayList`, and run the `eventIterable()` function within each class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create an interface containing the `eventIterable()` method, and make all of the classes implement that interface.

You can then use a list of that interface rather than a list of objects.

Answer (score 5):

Create an interface that represents this behavior (hard to know what it is) that has a single method called `eventIterable`. Then just change the return type to this interface.